# Getting ValueError 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5928: character maps to <undefined> in Pycharm

Tags: python, azure, api, debugging, virtual-machine

I'm building a component that uses Azure REST APIs to delete VMs, it was working fine before but now it's throwing an error 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5928: character maps to -undefined>

Not sure if this comes from my code or from a configuration of pycharm, the last seems more possible since I have changed the code multiple times and get the same error. Postman throws a 400 Bad Request Error when I call the endpoint. This is what I have written:

```
@app.route("/host/v1/vm/<hostname>", methods=["DELETE"])
@xlogger.func_logger("cloudx_vp_service", "execute_delete")
def execute_delete(hostname, **kwargs):
    
    try:
        execute_delete_db = ExecuteDeleteDB(hostname=hostname)
        response = execute_delete_db.get_vm_details(hostname=hostname)
        response = make_response(jsonify(response), http.HTTPStatus.OK)
    except ValueError as e:
        log.error(str("There's a Value error"))
        response = make_response(jsonify(str(e.args[0])), http.HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
```

This call the class in another class:

```
class ExecuteDeleteDB:
"""Execute VM Delete"""

@func_config("cloudx_vpcx_service")
@xlogger.set_logger("cloudx_vpcx_service", "executing_vm_deletion")
def __init__(self, hostname, **kwargs):
    """This method loads the configuration settings"""
    self.config = kwargs["config"]
    self.subscription_id = self.config["execute_delete"]["subscription_id"]
    self.resource_group = self.config["execute_delete"]["resource_group"]
    self.vm_name = hostname
    self.scope = self.config["execute_delete"]["scope"]
    self.headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    self.get_vm_url = self.config["execute_delete"]["get_vm_url"]
    self.get_locks_list_url = self.config["execute_delete"]["get_locks_list_url"]
    self.delete_locks_url = self.config["execute_delete"]["delete_locks_url"]
    self.get_disk_list_url = self.config["execute_delete"]["get_disks_list_url"]
    self.get_network_interface_url = self.config["execute_delete"]["get_network_interface_url"]
    self.delete_vm_url = self.config["execute_delete"]["delete_vm_url"]
    self.delete_disk_url = self.config["execute_delete"]["delete_disks_url"]
    self.delete_network_interface_url = self.config["execute_delete"]["delete_network_interface_url"]
    # logger setting
    self.log = self.logger

def get_vm_details(self, hostname):
    """
   This method is to fetch the details of the VM, network interfaces and disks.
    :return: None
    """
    log = xlogger.getChildLogger(self.log, "vpcx_execute_delete_db.get_vm_details")
    event = "get_vm_details"
    self.log.info(f"Event Details: Initiated {event}")
    try:
        azr_tkn = self.azr_auth_token()
        self.headers["authorization"] = f"Bearer {azr_tkn}"
        get_vm_url = self.get_vm_url.format(self.subscription_id, self.resource_group, hostname)
        response = requests.get(url=get_vm_url, headers=self.headers)
        event = {"event": str(event),
                        "event_details": f"Fetching VMs"}
        self.log.info(f"{event}")
        if response.status_code == http.HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED or http.HTTPStatus.OK:
            return response.json()
            event = {"event": str(event),
                     "event_details": f"VM fetched successfully"}
            self.log.info(f"{event}")

            data_disks_list = response.json()["properties"]["storageProfile"]["dataDisks"]
            if data_disks_list:
                self.data_disks = []
                event = {"event": str(event),
                         "event_details": f"Fetching VM data disks"}
                self.log.info(f"{event}")
                for data_disk in data_disks_list:
                    self.data_disks.append(data_disk["name"])

            network_interface_list = response.json()["properties"]["networkProfile"]["networkInterfaces"]
            if network_interface_list:
                self.network_interface_list = []
                event = {"event": str(event),
                         "event_details": f"Fetching VM Network Interface"}
                self.log.info(f"{event}")
                for network in network_interface_list:
                    self.network_interface_list.append(network["id"].split("/")[8])

            os_disk_list = response.json()["properties"]["storageProfile"]["osDisk"]
            if os_disk_list["managedDisk"]:
                event = {"event": str(event),
                         "event_details": f"Fetching VM managed OS disk"}
                self.log.info(f"{event}")
                self.managed_os_disk = os_disk_list["name"]

        else:
            log_msg = f"Failed to fetch list of VMs under that Subscription_ID \n {response.content}"
            log.info(log_msg)
            event = {"event": str(event), "event_details": log_msg}
            self.log.info(f"{event}")
            raise Exception(response.content)

    except Exception as error:
        log.exception(f'Exception occured while fetching VM : {str(error)}')
        msg = f"Exception occured while searching for specific VM : {str(error)}"
        raise Exception(msg)
```

Terminal shows the following issue:

```
2022-09-08 07:52:57,978 - vpcx_apis.execute_delete(line:282) - MainProcess(20512):Thread-2(13424) - execute_delete - ERROR  -There's a Value error:
```

This line that's fails refers to:

```
execute_delete_db = ExecuteDeleteDB(hostname=hostname)
```

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatting it like code (you may censor e.g. usernames in file paths if you consider the information sensitive). You will likely need to remove the exception handling temporarily for this. Processing the error to show a response to the user is hiding valuable information from the stack trace.

Comment: I just edited with the error message in terminal.